# WPF app performance really slow after running it for long time

Tags: wpf

I have created a WPF application. However, it works really slow if I kept it running for more than 1 hour. I have done a cod review and I'm sure I am not building any big list etc. How can I check, what is slowing down my application.

Comment: Does that happens only when app is minimized or unattended for hours?

Comment: I think may possibility of memory leak that is common with WPF applications. Try with a memory profiler.

Comment: No it happens even if the app is active

Comment: Only your app?  Other apps don't slow down?   Check process manager.  Check for virus.